# Best way to reuse code from two very similar functions

Tags: javascript

I have two functions doing basically the same thing, just in opposite order. I'd like some ideas on how to abstract them so there's no need to repeat so much code. Only way I could think of is creating three extra functions, which would then be called instead. While this makes the overall size a bit smaller, it actually results in more lines of code. Is there a better way of going around this?
I know it's a basic question, but I couldn't find anything similar.

```
function slideRight() {
var source = document.getElementById('pic1').src;
switch (source) {
case imgs[0]:
  source=imgs[1];
  document.getElementById('bullet1').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet2').style.backgroundColor="gray";
  document.getElementById('bullet3').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  break;
case imgs[1]:
  source=imgs[2];
  document.getElementById('bullet1').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet2').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet3').style.backgroundColor="gray";
  break;
case imgs[2]:
  source=imgs[0];
  document.getElementById('bullet1').style.backgroundColor="gray";
  document.getElementById('bullet2').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet3').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  break;
  }
document.getElementById('pic1').src = source;
}


function slideLeft() {
 var source = document.getElementById('pic1').src;
switch (source) {
case imgs[0]:
  source=imgs[2];
  document.getElementById('bullet1').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet2').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet3').style.backgroundColor="gray";
  break;
case imgs[1]:
  source=imgs[0];
  document.getElementById('bullet1').style.backgroundColor="gray";
  document.getElementById('bullet2').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet3').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  break;
case imgs[2]:
  source=imgs[1]
  document.getElementById('bullet1').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  document.getElementById('bullet2').style.backgroundColor="gray";
  document.getElementById('bullet3').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
  break;
 }
 document.getElementById('pic1').src = source;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone, they're all good ways! Hopefully I can upvote you for the help soon!

Comment: First of all, abstract away those `switch` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the snippet based on your code and made few assumptions about global variables.

I haven't been very strict with type checking. Maybe you can type check at your end. Let me know if this works.

```
var imgs = [ <array of images> ], index = 0, source = imgs[ index ];

function slide( direction, imgArray = [] ) {
  var imgArrLen = imgArray.length;

  if( imgArrLen ) {
    if( direction === 'left' ) {
      index = ( index + 1 ) < imgArrLen ? index + 1 : 0;
    } else {
      index = ( index - 1 ) >= 0 ? index - 1 : imgArrLen;
    }

    source = imgs[ index ];

    for( var i = 0; i < imgArrLen; i += 1 ) {
      var bgColorValue = 'transparent';

      if( index === i ) {
        bgColorValue = 'gray';
      }

      document.getElementById('bullet' + ( i + 1 ) ).style.backgroundColor = bgColorValue;
    }
  }
}
```

**To Slide Left:**

```
slide('left', imgs);
```

**To Slide Right:**

```
slide('right', imgs);
```

I hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using ternary operators? 
A ternary operator operates like an inline if statement for example,

```
way == 'right' ? "grey" :  "transparent";
```

Translated to normal if statement would evaluate to

```
if(way == 'right'){
   return "grey";
}else{
   return "transparent";
}
```

This would minimize your function by 1/2. I have provided a small sample of your function below, take a look.

```
function slide(way) {
    var source = document.getElementById('pic1').src;
    switch (source) {
       case imgs[0]:
         source=imgs[1];
         document.getElementById('bullet1').style.backgroundColor="transparent";
         document.getElementById('bullet2').style.backgroundColor = way == 'right' ? "grey" :  "transparent";
         document.getElementById('bullet3').style.backgroundColor=way == 'right' ? "transparent" : "grey";
         break;
       [... Rest of code ...]
}
```

I presume you would want to convert `way` parameter in the `slide` function to `lower`, so you can ignore the case when you're sending values to that function, but this is only a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible refactoring of your code:

```
var bullets = [];
bullets[0] = document.getElementById('bullet1');
bullets[1] = document.getElementById('bullet2');
bullets[2] = document.getElementById('bullet3');

var newIndex;
var sourceIndex;
var source = document.getElementById('pic1').src;

function slide(direction) {

    for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
        bullets[i].style.backgroundColor="transparent";
    }

    sourceIndex = imgs.indexOf(source);

    if (direction === 'right') {
        newIndex = (sourceIndex + 1);
        if (newIndex > (imgs.length - 1)) {newIndex = 0;}
    }

    else if (direction === 'left') {
        newIndex = (sourceIndex - 1);
        if (newIndex < 0) {newIndex = (imgs.length - 1);}
    }

    source = imgs[newIndex];
    bullets[newIndex].style.backgroundColor="gray";
    document.getElementById('pic1').src = source;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with es6 shortening:

```
function slide(isLeft) {
    var el = document.getElementById.bind(document),
    colors = { // move right colors:
        [imgs[0]]: ["transparent", "gray", "transparent"],
        [imgs[1]]: ["transparent", "transparent", "gray"],
        [imgs[2]]: ["gray", "transparent", "transparent"],
        // move left colors:
        [imgs[0]+"left"]: ["transparent", "transparent", "gray"],
        [imgs[1]+"left"]: ["gray", "transparent", "transparent"],
        [imgs[2]+"left"]: ["transparent", "gray", "transparent"],
    }[el('pic1').src + ( isLeft ? "left": "" )];
    // assign proper colors:
    el('bullet1').style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
    el('bullet2').style.backgroundColor = colors[1];
    el('bullet3').style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
    el('pic1').src = source;
}
```

I use an object to switch(), which is less boilerplate. It goes right by default, pass anything truthy to move left instead.